# Where is the documentation for this ex command?

Tags: cmdline

`:1` jumps to the first line, `:$` jumps to the last line, `:+` jumps to the next line, etc.

It seems to me that there is a default `ex` command which accepts a range and jumps to it: what's the name of this ex command?

Where can I find it in vim help? I guessed it might be in `various.txt`, but I can't find it.

Comment: It's unclear what you want from your question. Maybe add an example of what the command would do. Just assume the command is `command_name` and add in the question how you would invoke the command and what it would output.

Comment: There are already 3 examples, I don't have problem calling this commands, but I don't know the name of this command, and I want to know it.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood then. I guess you want to look at `:h cmdline-ranges`. But that is obvious from how the ex-commands are acting that these are just ranges.

Comment: It doesn't describe command line with only range.

Comment: Sorry, I am really unable to understand your question. Sorry for not being able to help.

Comment: My bad, my English is too awful to understand. Put my question in another way, i know how to jump to specific line in ex mode, but i want to know where to find "how to jump to specific line in ex mode" in vim help. Or are there a section in vim help that's about how to jump to line in ex mode?

Comment: The range in this usage uses the first part of the parameter list eg `:1` but if you do `:1,$-20 s` for example it uses the second optional parameter. Unix documentation, where most vim documentation, assumes this knowledge as an absolute

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This command has no name, but is simply the default behavior of the ex (and, notably, ed). Given a range, which may be one of the special sequences you mentioned, or a search, or even just a plain line number (e.g., `:42`), ex will jump to that spot in the file.

It does, however, have a place in the doc:

```
:help :[range]
```

---

As requested, an in-depth look at my help-searching process:

- `man ex`: Always a good start. This took me to the `vim` man-page, which more or less points to the online help
- `man ed`: Remembering that `ex` descends from `ed`, I thought I'd try here. I'm not sure if the behavior is documented there, but it was worth a shot
- `:help ex` led to `:help Ex-mode`, neither of which were helpful
- Remembering something about viusage and exusage, I tried `:help exusage`: an interesting command to run
- I didn't see a range-based command in the index... hm. What about `:help range`? Took me to a useful page, but not quite there
- Ok, commands taking ranges are documented like `:[range]command`, so maybe `:help [range]`: Not quite, that's just above where we were
- `:help :[range]`: at long last.

(This is slightly exaggerated: in reality, post-exusage I jumped straight to `:help :[range]` because that's the syntax of the command. It was a lucky guess.)

Comment: It tickles me to not be able to find such a basic thing in vim help. I shall accept it as the answer if no one objects for some time.

Comment: @dedowsdi me too. Ive cleaned up your question a bit and am about to go try finding it myself.

Comment: @dedowsdi see update

Comment: @D I had to ask, how did you find it?

Comment: @dedowsdi Uh, luck? Good guessing? Actually, I started with `help exusage`, and then that led me to a part of the index where i couldnt find it. So i thought well maybe ill try the range help (and I knew the syntax for the help doc bc it’s pretty standardized).

Comment: @D Trying to follow your route to find it. Got stuck after `:help exusage` and `.,$ilist \vline|cursor|move|range|jump`, i even cheated to search`:[range]` in `index.txt`, but  no clue was found. Need more detail.

Comment: @dedowsdi see update

Comment: Small thing but don't you mean you tried `:exusage` rather than `:help exusage`?

Comment: @BLayer both, actually